# Parent Container Not Expanding When Div is Toggled via jQuery

Tags: jquery, expand

I've tried to find a similar problem here, but have not been able to. If this has been answered somewhere else, please just point me in the right direction. I have inherited someone else's code and so it's a bit of a problem for me. I didn't write the basic code, I'm just trying to make changes for a client.

I have a page with a left container and a right container. The left container is set to float left. Inside this are several sections that "expand" via jQuery. The problem is when they expand they do not cause the parent container (the left container) to expand also.

See here: http://catalysthcr.com/your-needs/
Click on the + sign.

If I take all of this out of a left and right container then everything works perfectly, as I would expect it to. The parent container expands so you can see everything.

See here: http://catalysthcr.com/your-needs-two/

So, it must have something to do with the expanding content being placed inside a div that is floated.

I have a "clear" div after the left and right container divs set to clear both. I thought that should fix things, but it doesn't.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, or if you need more info from me I'm happy to provide. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

`.left-content` has `height: 361px` (via a jQuery function it looks like), it needs to be `auto` in order for the div to expand to contain the children elements.

Comment: Thank you! I've searched through the entire site and can't find anywhere that this is set, including in the jQuery file. Can you tell me where you are seeing this? Thanks again!

Comment: I'm not near a computer to check at the moment but I would guess you have a jQuery script that matches column height between the left and right divs so that they're equal, which is running on `$(window).load`.

Comment: Thanks, Josh! Yep, I found it, does exactly what you thought, makes the two divs equal. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be caused by the explicit "height" given to the element with the class "left-content".

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. I've searched and searched through all the code and can't find anywhere where the "left-content" element has a height set on it. Can you tell me where you are seeing this? Thanks again!

Comment: I've resolved it for now by including an !important css rule for this element to set height to auto, but would love to know where you are seeing the initial rule set so I can fix it at the source. Thanks!